# Package installing question, (Survival analysis)

Tags: installation, package, survival

I met this problem when I install the package “survminer”
Other packages are still available for installing except for this one.
How could I solve this problem?
Should I update my Rstudio ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The part with `namespace 'tibble' 2.1.3 is already loaded, but >= 3.0.0 is required` is telling you that you need to upgrade your `tibble` package to version > `3.0.0`. Try `update.packages(ask=F)`

Similar to [R install package loaded namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295443/r-install-package-loaded-namespace)